# creating a file with a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a text document with user inputted information but nothing is being created... Here is the code I have used for the button click:

```
runnerTestResultBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (capitanPasswordValidate()& permissionGranted) {

                if (capitanPasswordET.getText().toString().equals(capitanPassword)) {

                    createFile();

                } else {

                    capitanPasswordError.setText("Wrong Password!");
                    capitanPasswordError.requestFocus();


                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Also, here is the code I am using to create the file:

```
private void createFile() {

    String familiaName = familiaNamesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String FILE_NAME = familiaName + "_Runner_Test_Results.txt";
    String cafeteroTestResultString = runnerTestResult1.getText().toString();

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File file = new File(FILE_NAME);

    try {
            capitanPasswordError.setText("");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(cafeteroTestResultString.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "did not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Just a side note, I am making it so the user selects a choice from a spinner View in order to track down which file belongs to which person. it is under familiaName and will be part of the name of the file created. any feedback would be amazing, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You must check for permissions before reading or writing a file, Please add permission requests to manifests and request permissions for READ, WRITE operations at runtime,

**Here i have a simple solution, - (Multiple permission checking)**

```js
String[] permissions = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; // Here i used multiple permission check
```

**Then call it in Oncreate**

```
 if (checkPermissions()) {
            //  permissions  granted.
            getCallDetails();
        }
```

**Finally, copy the below code**

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permissions granted.
                    getCallDetails(); // Now you call here what ever you want :)
                } else {
                    String perStr = "";
                    for (String per : permissions) {
                        perStr += "\n" + per;
                    }
                    // permissions list of don't granted permission
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```